# Where and why "dispirited" lost its "s"?

Tags: etymology

That word just doesn't feel right, it's not "di" (like in "dipole), it's not "de" ("depressed"), it's not "dis" (at least not from the spelling point). When did it go wrong?

Comment: dispirit (v.)
"depress the spirits of, deprive of courage," 1640s; see dis- + spirit. https://www.etymonline.com/word/dispirit

Comment: But "dis-" never merges with a following "s", does it?

Comment: As a living prefix in English, it reverses or negatives what it is affixed to. Sometimes, as in Italian, it is reduced to s- (as in spend, splay, sport, sdain for disdain, and the surnames Spencer and Spence). https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-?ref=etymonline_crossreference

Comment: In classical Latin, dis- paralleled de- and had much the same meaning, but in Late Latin dis- came to be the favored form and this passed into Old French as des-, the form used for compound words formed in Old French, where it increasingly had a privative sense ("not"). In English, many of these words eventually were altered back to dis-, while in French many have been altered back to de-. The usual confusion prevails.

Comment: I guess you're asking why it's not "disspirited"? Simplification of duplicated/double letters is common in English when it doesn't affect pronunciation.